# Finding possible prefix palindromes

Tags: c++

We are given a string S of length N. We have to calculate number of prefixes which can be rearranged into palindromes. E.g: Consider string "abba"- "a", "abb" and "abba" are the prefixes which can be rearranged into palindromes.

My approach:
I tried to use XOR for solving this problem. For example a string containing even number of characters can be made palindrome if the xor of all characters in the string is 0.In case of strings having odd characters, the xor of all characters should be between 97 and 122, i.e a single character.

Here's a part of my code-

```
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    int a,n;
    int ans=1;
    n= s.length();
    a=s[0];
    for (int i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            a=a^(s[i]);
            if (i%2)
            {
                if (a==0)
                {
                    ans++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ((a>=97)&&(a<=122))
                {
                    ans++;
                }
            }
        }
    cout<< ans<< "\n";
```

I tried to run and it runs successfully for some test cases but fails for others. Any idea of what's wrong in this approach?

Comment: Please don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you want to check if a character is a lower-case letter use [`std::islower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/islower).

Comment: what you mean having said **prefix palindromes**

Comment: another approach for checking if `a` is letter is the function [`isalpha`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/)

Comment: @arsdever - prefix palindromes means all the prefixes which can be rearranged to form palindromes

Comment: Make a reversed copy of the string (`rbegin()` and `rend()` will give you the reversed range to copy), and then simply compare the first N characters, for N = 1 to the size of the string. Every match is a palindrome. Abort on the first mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution, based on the comments from OP:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;

    unsigned char_xor   = input[ 0 ];
    unsigned pal        = 1; // number of palindromes (initialized to 1, 
                             // since a singular letter is always a 
                             // palindrome)

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; input.size() >= i; ++i ) {
        char_xor ^= input[ i + 1 ];

        // check whether length of current prefix is:
        //   - odd: check whether it is a lowercase character
        //   - even: check whether it is equal to 0
        if ( ( i % 2 && std::islower( char_xor ) ) ||
             ( !( i % 2 ) && !char_xor ) ) {
            ++pal;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Amount of possible palindromes: " << pal << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

**The following assumption is incorrect (see comments below).**

As having understood from

> a string containing even number of characters can be made palindrome if the xor of all characters in the string is 0.In case of strings having odd characters, the xor of all characters should be between 97 and 122

you're making a mistake in checking whether the computed `XOR` is equal to 0/between 97 and 122 on each iteration (after `XOR`ing each character), whereas you should be checking it after iterating over the whole `std::string`. The following works with your given example of "abba" and, for instance, "aaaadcasdasdaffaaa" (having produced 12):

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

bool can_be_palindrome( const std::string& str ) {
    unsigned char_xor = str[ 0 ];

    // compute the xor of all characters
    for ( std::string::size_type i = 1; str.size() != i; ++i ) {
        char_xor ^= str[ i ];
    }

    // determine whether the input string has an even number of characters;
    // if so, return whether char_xor is equal to 0;
    // if not, return whether char_xor is a lowercase letter.
    return !( str.size() % 2 ) ? !char_xor : std::islower( char_xor );
}

int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;

    unsigned pal = 1; // number of palindromes (initialized to 1, since a 
                      // singular letter is always a palindrome)

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 2; input.size() >= i; ++i ) {
        // extract a prefix from the range [0; i) and determine whether it 
        // can become a palindrome
        if ( can_be_palindrome( input.substr( 0, i ) ) ) {
            ++pal;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Amount of possible palindromes: " << pal << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My idea was that at the end of `i^{th}`  iteration, I would get whether the prefix with first `i+1` characters is a palindrome or not. So after 1st iteration two lettered prefix will be checked, after the second iteration three lettered prefix and so on. The variable `a` will store the previous `XOR` and then I can just `XOR` the next character with the previous value of `a` to check for the next sub-string/prefix. Isn't this correct?

Comment: @dineshH oh, didn't think of it in that sense. Yeah, it seems correct and works. The problem in your code is that you check whether the current index (`i`) is odd, whereas you should be checking whether the length (`i + 1`) is odd. So change `if (i % 2)` to `if ((i + 1) % 2)`. Plus, you need to switch the conditions, since now you're checking whether `XOR` result is equal to `0` when the length is odd, which contradicts your statement in the OP. See edited answer.

Comment: Or, as presented in the answer, by starting from `i = 0` and using `str[i + 1]` for `XOR`ing and `i` for evenness checks.

Comment: Even though I checked the condition for `i` the statements of `if` and `else` have been swapped. So if `i` is odd then the condition for even is executed and vice versa.

Comment: Your approach seems really obscure or I'm simply not understanding you. Why are you looking into the 'future', when the `XOR` is based on the current character? Either way, the most sensible option imo seems to be to switch the bodies of the `if` statements, start at `i = 0` and compute the `XOR` of the `i + 1`th character.